# Cannot access session variables in ASHX handler file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ashx

I have an ASHX handler file that I am using for legacy purposes (we have a win32 app that cannot be updated that references an ASHX handler)

The following is the handler, which seems to work fine except it won't access session variables set elsewhere in the MVC app:

```
using Core.Helpers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace handlers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for hShowChosenTicketsFGL
    /// </summary>
    public class hShowChosenTicketsFGL : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState,  IReadOnlySessionState
    {
        public long orderId;

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            List<string> response = new List<string>();

            if (context.Session["OrderId"] == null)
            orderId = -1;
            else
                orderId = Convert.ToInt64(context.Session["OrderId"]);

            if (orderId == -1)
                orderId = Convert.ToInt64(context.Request.QueryString["OrderId"]);

            bool ifReturns = false;
            if (orderId.ToString().StartsWith("1111"))
                ifReturns = true;

            if (ifReturns)
                orderId = long.Parse(orderId.ToString().Substring(4));

            JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var fgl = new List<string>();

            if(HttpContext.Current.Session["ReceiptFGL"] != null)
            {
                var text = HttpContext.Current.Session["ReceiptFGL"].ToString();
                fgl.Add(text);


                HttpContext.Current.Session["ReceiptFGL"] = null;
            }

            var jsonReponse = json.Serialize(fgl);
            context.Response.Write(jsonReponse);
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
       }
   }
}
```

I had also tried the routing approach but couldn't get it to work, the app kept coming back and saying that the location was not found. This is the route I used:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "LegacyTicketGet",
    url: "handlers/hShowChosenTicketsFGL.ashx",
    defaults: new { controller = "API", action = "GetReceiptFGL" }
);
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I may be doing wrong, or how I might abandon the handler and use routing to route to a JsonResult action?

Comment: Not sure but perhaps the server (IIS) is grabbing the ashx request before your app gets its shot.  You could try an IIS rewrite rule to direct that .ashx request to a controller of your choosing.  Is the ashx in the same application as your mvc app?

Comment: I'm assuming you are answering the issue of the route not working? As without a route, the handler file is called, as I can step into it, it just does not pick up my previously set session variables.

Comment: Yes but I didn't do an answer because I didn't provide clear solutions.  To your session problem, I would think an ashx in the same application should be able to talk to the same session.

Comment: "we have a win32 app that cannot be updated that references an ASHX handler" - does this mean the app call the handler and does not bother to pass session cookie?

Comment: Well, it is a win32 app that wraps a browser. So I'm assuming the browser is handling the session cookie, as session variables worked perfectly fine in the ashx handlers that were used within the WebForms app I am porting to MVC.

Comment: Have you *verified* (i.e. using Fiddler) that cookie is actually still sent? Have you checked if session is even configured for new app?

Comment: Fiddler doesn't appear to pick up the traffic coming from the app. Wonderful :)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks, John.

To everyone else, the problem is the session cookie is not being sent by the app, as the request I am looking at is fired off outside of the wrapped browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. I had the same issue.

Make sure you inherit from System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState , so your ashx file class should be like below.

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
        {
            public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
            {
              string Name = "";
              if (context.Session["mysessionvar"] != null)
                 Name = context.Session["mysessionvar"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

Just calling localhost may not work. Surely works on IIS setup.

reference https://thedeveloperblog.com